# How to change the return value by spring aop

Tags: java, spring, aop

I have a method with a return value in DAO layer, I want to change the return value by spring AOP, according different requirement,s and then send to corresponding method in SERVICE layer; but i don't know how to do so.

Comment: I cannot help you with Spring AOP, but I highly suggest that you post some source code if you ever want help from the Stackoverflow community.

Answer (score 28):

You can apply an `@Around` aspect to the method whose return type should be modified. You can take a look at my [blog post](http://vikdor.blogspot.com/2012/10/memoize-in-java-using-spring-and-aspects.html) on how to add Spring AOP facet to a Spring application, then write an `@Around` aspect. I used this aspect for `Memoizing` results of a method, but in your case, you would take the return value of `ProceedingJoinPoint.proceed()`, typecast it to appropriate class, then modify it and return it.

In case you plan to return a completely different object altogether, then that would result in ClassCastException, unless the actual returned object is a subclass of the return type.