# Change type of returning value using AspectJ spring-aop

Tags: java, return, aspectj, spring-aop

I want to complete a JSON response received from controller adding e.g. a status attribute. In this regard, I'm going to use Aspect class, which @Around method return a custom class object.
In this case I get an error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: *.controller.RestResponse cannot be cast to java.util.List
```

Is there way to change returning in @ResponseBody type to custom type via aspectJ annotation @Around? I can't change controllers code!

Controller class:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/users")
public class UserController {

@Autowired
private UserService userService;

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public List<User> get() throws InterruptedException {
    return userService.getUsers();
}
...
}
```

Aspect class:

```
@Component
@Aspect
public class RestInterceptor {

@Pointcut("within(* controller.api.*)")
public void endpointMethod() {
}

@Around("endpointMethod()")
public RestResponse unifyResponse(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
    Object controllerResult = pjp.proceed();
    RestResponse result = new RestResponse(0, controllerResult);
    return result;
}
}
```

Custom class RestResponse:

```
public class RestResponse{

private int status;
private String message;
private Object data;

public RestResponse(int status, Object data) {
    this.status = status;
    this.data = data;
}

public RestResponse(int status, String message) {
    this.status = status;
    this.message = message;
}
//getters and setters
}
```

Comment: ClassCastException is normal situation in this case. Look at the [answer for this closed question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14017860/how-to-change-the-return-value-by-spring-aop). So I think you should find other solution.
I have the [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25020331/spring-mvc-how-to-modify-json-response-sent-from-controller)

Answer (score 0):

use ResponseBodyAdvice instead.

Answer (score -1):

I think there is some problem with your point cut.If you only want the point cut around get() method of controller class  you should have used something like this :

```
@Pointcut("execution(* package..Controller.get(..))")  .
```

In your case you can just check if the point cut applied by you is executing around get() method of Controller class  or some  other method in package controller.api.* by debugging the flow .

Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the operativeness! But I need to apply aspect to all methods of controller class and I see in debug mode that method unifyResponse is executed.

Comment: But fail when it try to return result.

Comment: You should use       @Pointcut("execution(* controller.api.Controller.*(..))") to excute all methods in controller class.Actually the point cut you have defined would get executed for all class in package controller.api if there are more than one.

Comment: If you are debugging the flow you can just perform a step into at pjp.proceed() to find out what method of  which class gets executed at this point cut.