# how to convert HTTPServletResponse into HttpEntity?

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, servlets

In my project i have multiple API's(implemented using Spring REST API).
Now i have this requirement that i have to manipulate the response in specific way before it is sent to client and changing it in every API method does not seems to be a good option.

Only solution i can think of is using **servlet.Filter** (by extending filter class)

```
 @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
> chain.doFilter(req, res);
```

and write my logic after

> chain.doFilter(req, res);

but i am struggling to convert ServletResponse or HTTPServletResponse into HttpEntity.

Please help me how can i achieve this ? and is there any better approach available ?

Thanks

**UPDATE**

@jny solution has helped me.

little code snippet to show how it works.

```
@ControllerAdvice(basePackages = { "com.test.controller" })   // package where it will look for the controllers.
public class ResponseFilter implements ResponseBodyAdvice<Object> {

    @Override
    public Object beforeBodyWrite(Object body, MethodParameter returnType, MediaType selectedContentType,
            Class<? extends HttpMessageConverter<?>> selectedConverterType, ServerHttpRequest request,
            ServerHttpResponse response) {
        //here you can manipulate the body the way you want.
        return body;
    }
```

important is that your controller should be annotated with **@ResponseBody**

Comment: Can you add some more detail?  What does the response look like before your proposed filter?  What do you want it to look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what exactly you need.
If you need to make changes of the body of the response,
if you use `Spring 4.1` or higher, you can use [`ResponseBodyAdvice`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/ResponseBodyAdvice.html) to manipulate the body of the response.

If you need to filter certain fields, there are other options available.
From documentation:

> Implementations may be may be registered directly with
>   RequestMappingHandlerAdapter and ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver or
>   more likely annotated with @ControllerAdvice in which case they will
>   be auto-detected by both.

Comment: as i have understood from the documentation , ResponseBodyAdvice needs to be called from method(before return response) itself and it is practically a lot of work. i was thinking to handle this logic in filter somehow. my motive is to read the response boda manipulate it and write it back in response.

Comment: Updated the answer to show that you DO NOT need to call it from method

Comment: exactly what i was looking for.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This may point you in the right direction: [Spring MVC: How to modify json response sent from controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25020331/spring-mvc-how-to-modify-json-response-sent-from-controller)

It involves wrapping the ServletResponse before invoking doFilter and using a custom ServletOutputStream that allows the response data to be manipulated after it would normally have been closed. HttpEntity is not involved.