# Spring boot application filter response body

Tags: spring, spring-boot, filter, httpresponse, servlet-filters

I am working on a spring boot application. I want to modify the response of the request by request body field "Id".

I have implemented below, but still getting just the name in the output while implementing.Any suggestions on implementing below would be helpful:

Below is the requestBody:

```
{
"id" : "123"
}
```

In response, I want to append that field to response id(fieldname from request body).
responseBody:

```
{
"name" : "foo123"  //name + id from request
}
```

**MyCustomFilter:**

```
public class TestFilter implements Filter {


    @Override
    public void doFilter(
            ServletRequest request,
            ServletResponse response,
            FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
       HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    final PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(baos);
    MultiReadHttpServletRequest wrapper = new MultiReadHttpServletRequest((HttpServletRequest) request);

    MyRequestWrapper req = new MyRequestWrapper(wrapper);
    String userId = req.getId();

    chain.doFilter(wrapper, new HttpServletResponseWrapper(res) {
        @Override
        public ServletOutputStream getOutputStream() throws IOException {
            return new DelegatingServletOutputStream(new TeeOutputStream(super.getOutputStream(), ps)
            );
        }

        @Override
        public PrintWriter getWriter() throws IOException {
            return new PrintWriter(new DelegatingServletOutputStream(new TeeOutputStream(super.getOutputStream(), ps))
            );
        }
    });

    String responseBody = baos.toString();

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    JsonNode node = mapper.readTree(responseBody);
    String name = node.get("name").astext();

    ((ObjectNode) node1).put("name", name + userId);

    chain.doFilter(wrapper, res);
}
```

**MyRequestWrapper:**

```
public class MyRequestWrapper extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {
    private ServletInputStream input;

    public MyRequestWrapper(ServletRequest request) {
        super((HttpServletRequest)request);
    }

    public String getId() throws IOException {
        if (input == null) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(IOUtils.toString(super.getInputStream()));
                String userId = jsonObject.getString("id");

                userId = userId.replaceAll("\\D+","");
                return userId;
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

**MultiReadHttpServletRequest.java**

`public class MultiReadHttpServletRequest extends HttpServletRequestWrapper` {

```
private byte[] body;

public MultiReadHttpServletRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
    super(request);
    try {
        body = IOUtils.toByteArray(request.getInputStream());
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        body = new byte[0];
    }
}

@Override
public BufferedReader getReader() throws IOException {
    return new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getInputStream(), getCharacterEncoding()));
}

@Override
public ServletInputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
    return new ServletInputStream() {
        ByteArrayInputStream wrapperStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(body);

        @Override
        public boolean isFinished() {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isReady() {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void setReadListener(ReadListener readListener) {

        }

        @Override
        public int read() throws IOException {
            return wrapperStream.read();
        }
    };
}
```

}

Any suggestions are appreciated. TIA.
Nte: After update i am not able to see the updated response as output. I am still seeing just the name but not id appended to it.

Comment: This will not be valid JSON "foo"+"123"

Comment: @SimonMartinelli updated the question. I mean to say concatenate together in the response. Any suggestions on this please?

Comment: Just pass your own implementation of request/response into filter chain: `chain.doFilter(req /*MyRequestWrapper*/, res);`. Or try to put your code just after chain.doFilter(). Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25020331/spring-mvc-how-to-modify-json-response-sent-from-controller).

Comment: @slesh updated the question. Actually i am not seeing the modifed response in the output. Any suggestions please>

Answer (score 0):

The one issue I see with your own implementation of ServletRequest is that you call `super.getInputStream()` instead of `request.getInputStream()`. Your own request is empty by default, that's why you're getting time out exception. You have to delegate a call to the actual request:

```
public class MyRequestWrapper extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {
    private ServletInputStream input;

    public MyRequestWrapper(ServletRequest request) {
        super((HttpServletRequest)request);
    }

    public String getId() throws IOException {
        if (input == null) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(IOUtils.toString(/*DELETEGATE TO ACTUAL REQUEST*/request.getInputStream()));
                String userId = jsonObject.getString("id");

                userId = userId.replaceAll("\\D+","");
                return userId;
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually i just tried MultiReadHttpServletRequest (Updated in question). But still i am getting the original response. But not the updated response.