# Why cannot change response type using spring AOP, except return Object

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, aspectj, spring-aop

I'm using Spring AOP to point cut my controller method and trying to return common structure response to front end.
The definition should be like below:

```
public class CommonResponse {

private String status;

private String message;

private Object data;
}
```

I also have a point definition as below:

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class PostMessageInterceptor {


@Pointcut("within(org.moa.controller.*)")
public void postMessageConvert() {}

@Around("postMessageConvert()")
public CommonResponse modifyResult(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) {
    CommonResponse response = new CommonResponse();
    try {
        Object result = pjp.proceed();
        response.setStatus("success");
        response.setData(result);
    }catch(Throwable t) {
        response.setStatus("failure");
        response.setMessage(t.getMessage());
    }
    return response;
}
}
```

For example, when method in controller return type is `Map<String,String>`, after `modifyResult` execution, the return type has covert to `CommonResponse` from `Map<String,String>`, then Spring AOP will occur an exception `java.lang.ClassCastException: CommonResponse cannot be cast to java.util.Map`

If I change return type of this method to Object, it will working fine.

I just want to is this designed as this? Otherwise, is there any way that I can achieve this goal without modify return type to Object. Because it feels weird all methods return same type Object.

Comment: Well the caller of the method sure expects to receive a `Map`, don't they? So why would it be acceptable to return anything else than declared?

Comment: I want make my method declared more specified. But I also want to return consistent json format to fronend.

Answer (score 1):

you cannot change the return type of the surrounded method. The mechanics of the JVM do not allow that (See the answer of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14017860/how-to-change-the-return-value-by-spring-aop) question).

The caller of your method compiles his code against the interface of the original method, but after executing your adivice the method is returning a different type. How should that work?

A possibility would be to use an interface and return a different implementation, created by your advice, e.g.:

```
interface MyReturnType {
  int getStatus();
  Map<String, String> getData();
}

class MethodReturnType implements MyReturnType {
  int getStatus() { throw NotImplementedException(); } 
  // should never be called; every other method in the interface can be implemented in the exact same way


  Map<String, String> getData() { return data; } // I omit the constructor and field decleration here
}

class AdviceReturnType implements MyReturnType {
  int status;
  Map<String, String> data;

  int getStatus() { return status; } 
  Map<String, String> getData() { return data; }
}


public MyReturnType myAdvicedMethod(...) {
  // ...
  return new MethodReturnType(myCalculatedData);
}

public Object aroundAdvice(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) {
  MyReturnType retVal = (MyReturnType) pjp.proceed();
  // calculate status and stuff
  return new AdviceReturnType(retVal.getData(), caluclatedStatus, ...);
}
```