# AspectJ and Spring AOC

Tags: java, aop, aspectj, spring-aop

I'm writing a custom AOP method-handler and I have two methods with different annotations:

```
@AfterReturning(value = "@annotation(Metric)", returning = "response")
public void afterReturning(JoinPoint joinPoint, ResponseWithStatus response) {
    final Signature signature = joinPoint.getSignature();
    final int responseStatus = response.getStatus();
    metrics.putIfAbsent(signature, resultCounters);
    if (responseStatus == ResponseStatus.SUCCESS.getValue()) {
        System.out.println("Method " + signature + " returned its result");
        metrics.get(signature).get(SUCCESS).increment();
    } else if (errorCodes.contains(responseStatus)) {
        System.out.println("Method " + signature + " returned error");
        metrics.get(signature).get(ERROR).increment();
    } else if (businessErrorCodes.contains(responseStatus)) {
        System.out.println("Method " + signature + " returned business error");
        metrics.get(signature).get(BUSINESS_ERROR).increment();
    }
}

@AfterThrowing(value = "@annotation(Metric)", throwing = "exception")
public void afterThrowing(JoinPoint joinPoint, Exception exception) {
    final Signature signature = joinPoint.getSignature();
    final Class<? extends Exception> exceptionClass = exception.getClass();
    final String exceptionName = exceptionClass.getName();
    metrics.putIfAbsent(signature, resultCounters);
    if (exceptionClass.equals(ValidationWebFault_Exception.class)) {
        System.out.println("Method " + signature + " threw " + exceptionName);
        metrics.get(signature).get(ERROR).increment();
    }
}
```

But my methods are being handled only by `@AfterThrowing` method. How I can use both of them for ONE annotation?

Comment: To understand, the method is not advised when method returns successfully? An alternative is to use an @Around advice and handle based on return / exception

Comment: @R.G Yes, it works only with throwing an Exception. But I need different logic after success and an exception

Comment: Do check the return type mismatch if any . @Around can be used execute two different logic on successful return and exception using a try catch block . A sample format can be found in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61765084/4214241)

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved the problem by myself. I just need to use `Object response` instead of `ResponseWithStatus response` in my `afterReturning()` method

Comment: `ResponseWithStatus response` is fine if (and only if) all your intercepted methods also return that type or any of its subtypes. `Object` could be overkill if you can be more specific in your matching type expression. But your expected return type probably was just something else.